# How to properly escape single and double quotes in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to customize the scrollbar in QT as below:

```
const QString name = "scrollbarIssue";
float btn_dimension = 8;
QString source = "::-webkit-scrollbar-button {height:"+ QString::number(btn_dimension) +"px; background: black; display: block;}"
                       "::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement { background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=''http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'' width=''"+ QString::number(btn_dimension) +"'' height=''"+ QString::number(btn_dimension) +"'' fill=''%235a6268''><polygon points=''0,50 100,50 50,0''/></svg>\"); }"
                       "::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment { background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=''http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'' width=''"+ QString::number(btn_dimension) +"'' height=''"+ QString::number(btn_dimension) +"'' fill=''%235a6268''><polygon points=''0,0 100,0 50,50''/></svg>\"); }";


QString myFuncStr = "(function() {"
            "    css = document.createElement('style');"
            "    css.type = 'text/css';"
            "    css.id = '" + name + "';"
            "    document.head.appendChild(css);"
            "    css.innerText = "+ '"'+ source +'"' + ";"
            "})()";
```

In **source** variable, I escaped single quote by using two single quotes and I think this might be causing issue.

**myFuncStr** contains the value:

```
"(function() {    css = document.createElement('style');    css.type = 'text/css';    css.id = 'scrollbarIssue';    document.head.appendChild(css);    css.innerText = \"::-webkit-scrollbar-button {height:8px; background: black; display: block;}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement { background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=''http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'' width=''8'' height=''8'' fill=''%235a6268''><polygon points=''0,50 100,50 50,0''/></svg>\"); }::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment { background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=''http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'' width=''8'' height=''8'' fill=''%235a6268''><polygon points=''0,0 100,0 50,50''/></svg>\"); }\";})()"
```

So, if the function inside the string above is run in browser console, it give below error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Can anyone please help how to properly escape the single/double quotes in QT C++?

Comment: Usually by standard escape sequence i.e _backslash_ \

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes with backslashes:

```
const auto example = QString("He said \"awesome\"");
qDebug() << example;
```

Prints:

```
He said: "awesome"
```

The same applies to a single quote. See this [table](http://gillius.org/ctut/app_a.htm) for more details.

If you are using C++11, you can use raw [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
const auto example = R"He said "awesome"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape to prevent a premature end of your string.

So in regular double quoted strings you only need to escape the backslash (always), double quote (and the newline):

```
QString str = "A string with a \\ backslask, \"double\" and 'single' quotes";

// stackoverflow's code highlighting isn't sophisticated enough for this:
QString str = "A string \
spanning two code lines";
```

In C++ single quotes always represent a single char, so the only time you need to escape a single quote is if you mean the *character*:

```
char singleQuote = '\'';
```